# redox signaling molecules and electrolysis

Tags: biochemistry

There is a product whose presentation screams of snake oil, allegedly consisting of nothing but electrically treated salt water. The product is claimed to be chock full of "redox signaling molecules" that have lots of health benefits.

I am not a chemist, and I certainly don't want to promote this (un-named) product; I just want a different perspective on it.  My understanding is that electrolysis of salt water produces some mix of $\ce{H_2, O_2, Na, Cl, NaOH}$, and $\ce{NaClO, NaClO_3}$ depending on the configuration of the reactor, with possible inclusion of other substances due to decomposition of the electrodes.

A search on PubMed turned up several papers describing positive effects (in mice) of consuming water containing dissolved $\ce{H_2}$. I haven't found anything indicating that there are health benefits from consuming the other electrolysis products of salt water.

My question is this:  Could any of the other substances produced by electrolysis of $\ce{NaCl}$ in water ($\ce{O2, Na,Cl, NaOH,}$ and $\ce{NaClO, NaClO_3}$) act as "redox signaling molecules" as claimed by the manufacturer?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE!  Please note that formulas can be better expressed with \$\ce{}\$ for chemical formulas/equations, \$\mathrm{}\$ for math term/equations, and \$\pu\$ for units. More information is available in [this meta post](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3044/23561) Also, take a minute to look over the [help center](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) and [tour page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand our guidelines and question policies.

Comment: @orthocresol, the term "redox signaling molecules" is used in cell biology, e.g.,[https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c997/ef50e63b833d60410b6ca0b4e0c838aa930a.pdf], and seems to refer primarily to small molecules containing oxygen, produced by mitochondria and diffusing to neighboring cells.  Haven't been able to find an explicit definition yet.

Comment: Without seeing the ad, or knowing the product, I'd say that it is snake oil. The electrolysis of NaCl in water will yield bleach -- hardly a healthful substance to be drinking, unless you're using a dilute solution to disinfect the water.

Comment: @S.McGrew you are right and I had deleted my hasty comment - although not before you saw it! Sadly, a google search for redox signalling molecules seems to give more pseudoscience than science...